# how to differentiate 7" (1024*600) tablet and 10.1" (1280*800) tablet at design time

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing app for tablets which supports 7" 1024*600 resolution and 10.1" 1280*800 resolution. So in order to differentiate them I am making folder layout-large-mdpi for 7" and layout-xlarge-mdpi for 10.1". But while I run the app, it runs from layout-xlarge-mdpi folder for both the device. Can anyone please guide me on how to differentiate these two tablets through folders in xml?

Comment: read this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674897/how-to-set-layout-on-7-two-different-tablet>

Comment: yes I just saw that question while searching for the answer and am trying that........... was going through that only........thanks for your suggestion though :)

Comment: means ur problem will be solve now!!!!

Comment: No it is still taking from same folder i.e. layout-xlarge-hdpi for both the device :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two different for layout also one layout for 7Inch as layout-sw600dp and for 10'inch as layout-720dp. and in the images make drawable also as drawable-large-hdpi(7Inch) and drawable-xlarge-mdpi(10Inch).

[image: Check These resource folder image.]

Comment: I already tried that but it is giving exception if I dont keep any file in layout or layout-land folder and only keep file in layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw720dp-land accordingly..........any idea why???? And if i put file in layout folder, it takes that file as default for both the device ..........????????

Comment: I have done these example theres is no need for layout and layout-land i have made that for mobile configuration. i have done these example and it is working succesfully. file show default only if u have used the same images for both...!!!!

Comment: I got it!!!!!!!!! The reason it was throwing exception was that I was running that in the emulator with api level 9 while these folders are supported after api level 11......

Comment: @RuchitShah If i use sw600 and sw720 my android console shows no support for 800*!280 devices. what should i do?